# Opening a file in a new window in macOS?

Tags: macos, file, window, atom-editor

Pretty much what the title says.
I would like when I use File -> Open or Cmd + O to open a file/directory, Atom would open it in a new Atom editor window not in a new tab inside the existing editor window.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Going to File > Open Folder and selecting a folder, Atom *does* create a new instance. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I'm using Atom 1.17.2 x64. In the File menu I only have the Open... option. Nothing called Open Folder. Using that Open option brings up the Finder (OS X) where I can choose which folder or file to open. That option opens the project in a new Atom Tab not a new Window (instance) of Atom.

Comment: Try pressing COMMAND+SHIFT+O, if it works. Also, when you say "project" I assume this means that the *directory* will be seen in *Tree View*. If you're referring to a *file*, this changes the question.

Comment: No, I don't want to add a directory to my current Tree View. I want atom to open it in a completely new window not a tab inside my current window if I use Cmd+O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open a file in a new window using Atom in a mac, at most you can [deactivate the option "Always Show Tab Bar" in Settings > Packages > tabs](https://www.reddit.com/r/Atom/comments/3xhm0e) AND open the window *before* opening a file:
[image]

You can think a "window" as a "projects" container.. so when you just open a file is like you are opening it in the current project for this reason you will see it in a new tab inside the window.
In this way is like you are opening a one-file project, hidding his single tab bar.

The result: [image]
If you need to switch to another file in the same path or close you can just open the "tree view" (cmd+):[image]

Comment: Thanks, that indeed makes opening directories appear in a new window. Doesn't work for files though but I guess that's fine. I don't need new window for every file but for every directory.

Comment: I've tried with single files and work fine.. And if you use the "tree view" you can easily switch to another file in the directory! SO you'll have a new window for every directory showing one file at time if you want that